# Are there any cyclic normal subgroups of the absolute Galois group?

Tags: number-theory, galois-theory

Let G be the Galois group of automorphisms of the field of algebraic numbers.  It is a topological group.

Let N be a closed normal subgroup of G.  It is another topological group.

Can N be topologically generated by a single element?